# CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE constant and cvCreatTrackbar method are undefined

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an issue when I want to use CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE constant and cvCreatTrackbar method in openCV library, I had insert the include folder in  "Additional include library" in project setting in Visual Studio and also add vc14/lib folder in "Additional Library Directory" in "Linker" tab in project setting, and i also include them in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"  
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
```

but then i face the error : "CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE is undefined" and "cvCreatTrackbar is undefined". What is the problem ?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: What version of **OpenCV** are you using - the *includes* changed between v2 and v3.

Comment: how can i understand which version i'm using? i have download it from here which is i think its version is 4!!?? "https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.0.0/opencv-4.0.0-vc14_vc15.exe/download"

Comment: why don't you just start with OpenCV examples like [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/introduction/windows_visual_studio_opencv/introduction_windows_vs.cpp) and [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d6a/tutorial_trackbar.html)?

Comment: It's not about "How to use openCV library", my problem is why those constant and method are undefined?

Comment: because you're using the obsolete C api which has been removed in version 4.0. Use the C++ api as explained in all recent tutorials: `cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`, `cv::createTrackbar` and so on... like shown in the tutorial I linked

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I should have use WINDOWS_AUTOSIZE and creatTrackbar instead, and then it works fine.